# OneToMany association in grails domain classes

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I want one to many association between the `Person` and `Address` domain class which will be more like :

```
create table person (id bigint),
               version bigint not null,
               primary key (id))

create table address (id bigint),
               person_id bigint not null,
               primary key (id))
```

I tried to establish oneToMany Relation between these two tables so that `one` person can have `n` number of addresses.

```
class Person{

static hasMany = [
        addresses: Address
]

}


class Address{

Address address

}
```

This is how I  think it should work, i tried serveral other option, but none worked as wanted. Either I get an crosstable or an error when starting the application.

Thanks for help

Comment: why are you creating the tables manually?? Grails do it automatically on startup if dbCreate is set to update.  The Abhinandan answer is right, but you don't need to create the tables.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do establish `one-to-many` relationship between the `Domain class` `Person` & `Address` as given below-

`Person` Domain class

```
class Person{

static hasMany = [addresses: Address]
}
```

`Address` Domain class

```
class Address{

static belongsTo = [person : Person]
}
```

Please go through the [grails documentation for gorm](http://docs.grails.org/2.4.4/guide/GORM.html#oneToMany) to understand the 
domain class relationships in depth.